What will be the size of program file when I comment all the code snippet?
I had a doubt in memory allocation while programming in c.
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,a[10];
    printf("Enter the no.of element you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the element: ");
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i, a[i]);
    }

}

I programmed to insert the elements in an array variable. And the size of the file size is attached.
File size
I tried to comment all the code snippet and checked the size of the program file.
 #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
/*  int n,a[10];
    printf("Enter the no.of element you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the element: ");
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i, a[i]);
    }
*/
}


But the file size is 262bytes. Before I comment the code it shows 258bytes.
What happens in the memory while I comment the code snippets?
File size

Are you referring to the size of the source file? You have more characters in the source to comment your code. Isn't it expected that the size of a longer text file is larger? The executable is smaller, right?

The source file still has to store the commented text (so you can uncomment it later).

You have added four charactgers to your source file so it is now four characters larger than before. You need to understand that a source file is just a lot of text, and what ever changes you make to it will be reflected purely in terms of the number of characters inside it.

Welcome to SO. Please do not add pure text information as picture. Instead copy&paste the text into your question. Copying text from a terminal is some basic skill any programmer needs.

The text in your source file clearly exists, since you can view it. It has to be stored somewhere. Commenting out code does not affect the source file size - rather it will increase it since /* etc has to be stored somewhere too. Commenting out only affects the built program memory size when executed.
Source file size (on the hard drive), program memory size when executed (in RAM or flash) and binary executable size (on the hard drive or similar non-volatile memory) are three completely different and mostly unrelated things.
In general it is recommended to gain some basic PC computer knowledge before learning programming. Where are files stored, where are programs executed and so on.
